# Need DISTINCT results inside FOR XML statement, but have to sort on data not included in FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL FOR XML statement where I'm transforming text to use in a comma-delimited list within the STUFF function. We're listing degrees earned by students at a university. The table the data is pulling from lists the full name of the school the student attended and the four-digit graduation year. I am transforming the table to represent a code for the school and a two-digit, shortened grad year with an apostrophe. This is going into an XML list such that alumni with multiple degrees can have all their degrees listed together. For instance, the following:

```
College of Arts & Sciences, 1999
Law School, 2001
Graduate School, 2006
```

Becomes this for use on event nametags:

```
A&S '99, Law '01, Grad '06
```

I'm finding our tables have duplication for some degrees. For instance, one list may show up as:

```
A&S '99, A&S '99, Grad '05
```

I want to eliminate such duplication. However, I need to keep the text formatted as shown. I also need to keep the degrees in the order they were earned.

I attempted to make my SELECT statement within my STUFF function DISTINCT. However, because I need to sort by a field, [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR], that is not actually contained in the data being output, I get an error stating "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." However, I can not have the full preferred class year in the list and keep the formatting as desired. I also can not simply sort on the results, as the sort value is not necessarily determined by a value included in those results.

I've also tried grouping on either the (re-)translated results or input fields with no success. I've also tried using a temporary table, which merely produces a litany of errors.

This statement produces the duplicated degrees & years:

```
stuff((select iif([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR]=0, '',', ' +
     (case
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Arts & Sciences' then 'Arts'
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Business Administration' then 'Bus Ad'
      end) + ' ''' + right(cast([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] as nvarchar),2))
     from [dbo].[V_QUERY_EDUCATIONALHISTORY] as [CollegeTable] 
     where [V_QUERY_REGISTRANT\Constituent].[ID] = [CollegeTable].[CONSTITUENTID]
     order by [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] asc
     for XML path ('')),1,2,'') as [DegreeHistoryShort],
```

This statement gives me the "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified" error.

```
stuff((select distinct iif([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR]=0, '',', ' +
     (case
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Arts & Sciences' then 'Arts'
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Business Administration' then 'Bus Ad'
      end) + ' ''' + right(cast([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] as nvarchar),2))
     from [dbo].[V_QUERY_EDUCATIONALHISTORY] as [CollegeTable] 
     where [V_QUERY_REGISTRANT\Constituent].[ID] = [CollegeTable].[CONSTITUENTID]
     order by [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] asc
     for XML path ('')),1,2,'') as [DegreeHistoryShort],
```

This statement throws myriad syntax errors with just about every command in the table (trying to use a select around the select).

```
stuff(select distinct * from (select iif([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR]=0, '',
     (case
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Arts & Sciences' then 'Arts'
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Business Administration' then 'Bus Ad'
      end) + ' ''' + right(cast([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] as nvarchar),2))
     from [dbo].[V_QUERY_EDUCATIONALHISTORY] as [CollegeTable] 
     where [V_QUERY_REGISTRANT\Constituent].[ID] = [CollegeTable].[CONSTITUENTID]
     order by [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] asc)
     for XML path ('')),1,2,'') as [DegreeHistoryShort],
```

I'm either stuck with the duplication or having to somehow incorporate the full class year, which I can't include.

Comment: Please provide table schema and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out myself. Group on both fields with [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] first.

```
stuff((select iif([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR]=0, '',', ' +
     (case
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Arts & Sciences' then 'Arts'
        when [EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] = 'College of Business Administration' then 'Bus Ad'
      end) + ' ''' + right(cast([PREFERREDCLASSYEAR] as nvarchar),2))
     from [dbo].[V_QUERY_EDUCATIONALHISTORY] as [CollegeTable] 
     where [V_QUERY_REGISTRANT\Constituent].[ID] = [CollegeTable].[CONSTITUENTID]
     group by [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR],[EDUCATIONALPROGRAM]
     order by [PREFERREDCLASSYEAR],[EDUCATIONALPROGRAM] asc
     for XML path ('')),1,2,'') as [DegreeHistoryShort],
```